# Error when running "make check" for glib-2.32.4

Tags: compiling, glib

I get the following error while installing `glib`.

```
ERROR:thread.c:147:test_thread4: assertion failed: (thread == NULL).
```

What is the issue and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `make check` in glib comes in last. `make check` depends on the  desktop-file-utils-0.20, which in turn depend on an installed glib, so that one should make sure that the desktop-file-utils are installed, working and at a correct version before running `make check`. The canonical way would be to first install the new glibc, then desktop-file-utils, and then, at the very end, do `make check`.

In general, an error during check is a reason to worry, at least in a professional setting. Failure of a test may mean that some particular condition can bring the system to its knees, even if the system runs fine 99.99% of the time.

In this particular case, you can directly look into the source code of glib to understand what is happening. Here is the relevant function:

```
/* test that thread creation fails as expected,
 * by setting RLIMIT_NPROC ridiculously low
 */
static void
test_thread4 (void)
{
#ifdef HAVE_PRLIMIT
  struct rlimit ol, nl;
  GThread *thread;
  GError *error;
  gint ret;

  getrlimit (RLIMIT_NPROC, &nl);
  nl.rlim_cur = 1;

  if ((ret = prlimit (getpid(), RLIMIT_NPROC, &nl, &ol)) != 0)
    g_error ("prlimit failed: %s\n", g_strerror (ret));

  error = NULL;
  thread = g_thread_try_new ("a", thread1_func, NULL, &error);
  g_assert (thread == NULL);
  g_assert_error (error, G_THREAD_ERROR, G_THREAD_ERROR_AGAIN);
  g_error_free (error);

  if ((ret = prlimit (getpid (), RLIMIT_NPROC, &ol, NULL)) != 0)
    g_error ("resetting RLIMIT_NPROC failed: %s\n", g_strerror (ret));
#endif
}
```

The error occurs ad the line

```
g_assert( thread == NULL ) ;
```

The test function changes the RLIMIT_PROC to a value of 1 (`nl.rlim_cur=1`, which limits the number of threads the current process can have). With that setting, creation of a new thread (`g_thread_try_new()` call) should fail and return `NULL`. For some reason, this does not happen.

Either there is a bug in the test suite, or a problem with glibc, or there was a problem correctly building glibc. In any case, incorrect return values from thread management library calls would make me very nervous.